# How do sort one XML node based on the order of another?

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

I am ashamed to admit that I have spent 7 straight hours trying to make this work. I want to sort the output from the first node using the order of the second node.

**XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<data>
    <content>
        <section link-id="86" link-handle="Start" value="Start" />
        <section link-id="23" link-handle="george-orwell" value="Orwell, George" />
        <section link-id="24" link-handle="aldous-huxley" value="Huxley, Aldous" />
        <section link-id="26" link-handle="robert-lewis-stevenson" value="Stevenson, Robert Louis" />
    </content>
    <datasource>
        <entry id="86">
            <name handle="start">Start</name>
            <order handle="0">0</order>
        </entry>
        <entry id="23">
            <name handle="george-orwell">Orwell, George</name>
            <order handle="1">1</order>
        </entry>
        <entry id="26">
            <name handle="robert-lewis-stevenson">Stevenson, Robert Louis</name>
            <order handle="2">2</order>
        </entry>
        <entry id="24">
            <name handle="aldous-huxley">Huxley, Aldous</name>
            <order handle="3">3</order>
        </entry>
    </datasource>
</data>
```

**XSLT**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:key name="sort-key" match="/data/datasource/entry" use="." />
    <xsl:template match="data">
        <html>
            <body>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="content" />
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="content">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="section">
            <xsl:sort select="key('sort-key', .)/@id"/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="section">
        Section: <xsl:value-of select="@value"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Current and incorrect output**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<html><body>
Section: Start
Section: Orwell, George
Section: Huxley, Aldous
Section: Stevenson, Robert Louis</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What value is order criteria?

Comment: There is not criteria other than to be ordered like the second node. The reason for this "guide" node is there there is no other criteria (alpha etc.) used. Looking for a way to explicitly set.

Answer (score 0):

From looking at your XML, it looks like you actually want to look up the **entry** elements by their **id**, so you should probably define your key like so:

```
<xsl:key name="sort-key" match="/data/datasource/entry" use="@id" />
```

Then, assuming the **handle** attribute is always sequentially in order, they **xsl:sort** command would look like this

```
<xsl:sort select="key('sort-key', @link-id)/order/@handle"/>
```

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:key name="sort-key" match="/data/datasource/entry" use="@id" />
    <xsl:template match="data">
        <html>
            <body>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="content" />
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="content">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="section">
            <xsl:sort select="key('sort-key', @link-id)/order/@handle"/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="section">
        Section: <xsl:value-of select="@value"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

But are you approaching this from the wrong direction? Why don't you start off by selecting second nodes directly, and then use **xsl:apply-templates** to select the corresponding first node with the key.

Try this XSLT as an alternative

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:key name="section" match="section" use="@link-id" />
    <xsl:template match="data">
        <html>
            <body>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="datasource/entry" />
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="entry">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="key('section', @id)" />
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="section">
        Section: <xsl:value-of select="@value"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```